# Why confirmation pop-up doesn't show the message I've defined for it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, confirm

Here is my code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
    var el = document.getElementById("qandatextarea");
    if( el && el.value && !DontAskBeforeExit){
        var message='ding ding';
        return message;
    }
}
```

But it shows this pop-up:

[image]

Why? I never told it this message:

> Changes you made may not be saved.

Well where it comes from? And why it doesn't show the message I've defined for it? (`dib ding`)

---

The result of this is also the same as the above one:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
    var el = document.getElementById("qandatextarea");
    if( el && el.value && !DontAskBeforeExit){
        var message = 'ding ding';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }
        if (evt) { 
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload a quick look at this has some warnings/notes. Notably: `When this event returns an undefined value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog. In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."`

Answer (score 2):

This functionality has been removed from several major browsers.  See [the compatibility section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility).  Notice that there is a section for "Custom text support removed".  Chrome 51 and FF 44 have removed the ability to customize the text.